# how to avoid undefinedfilename error when piping a2ps output to ps2pdf

Tags: linux, pdf

I am trying to write a bash function to convert a text file to PDF using a combination of a2ps and ps2pdf. To convert exc.cpp I have the following command:

```
a2ps -M a4 -B -1 -o - exc.cpp | ps2pdf  -sPAPERSIZE=a4 -o exc.pdf -
```

But I get an error indicating undefined filename the following error output:

```
GPL Ghostscript 9.04 (2011-08-05)
Copyright (C) 2011 Artifex Software, Inc.  All rights reserved.
This software comes with NO WARRANTY: see the file PUBLIC for details.
[exc.cpp (C++): 2 pages on 2 sheets]
[Total: 2 pages on 2 sheets] sent to the standard output
Error: /undefinedfilename in (.setpdfwrite)
Operand stack:

Execution stack:
   %interp_exit   .runexec2   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   2   %stopped_push   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   false   1   %stopped_push
Dictionary stack:
   --dict:1160/1684(ro)(G)--   --dict:0/20(G)--   --dict:77/200(L)--
Current allocation mode is local
Last OS error: 2
GPL Ghostscript 9.04: Unrecoverable error, exit code 1
```

Is there some way to specify to ps2pdf a value for the filename to avoid this error? Or is there a simpler way to convert a text file to PDF?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`a2ps` and `ps2pdf` do not share the same syntax.

According to [UNIX man pages : ps2pdf (1)](http://www.ma.utexas.edu/cgi-bin/man-cgi?ps2pdf+1), the basic syntax of `ps2pdf` is

```
ps2pdf  [options...] {input.[e]ps|-} [output.pdf|-]
```

This will work:

```
a2ps -M a4 -B -1 -o - exc.cpp | ps2pdf -sPAPERSIZE=a4 - exc.pdf
```